# Why does catting a symlinked file and redirecting the output to the original file make the latter file empty?

Tags: symlink

Here's how to reproduce it:

```bsh
echo 'the original file' > orig
ln -s orig symb # now symb is symlinked to orig
cat symb > orig # this makes orig an EMPTY FILE, but why?
```

`orig` becomes an empty file after the third command, but why?

Comment: Your command is exactly the same as `cat orig >orig`. Are you thinking you're doing something different?

Comment: I think you are victim to the misconception that the `cat` command performs the redirection. If this is what you think, you are wrong. It is the shell. Before executing `cat`, the shell processes `> orig`. This means that it creates an empty `orig` if it doesn't exist, or it resets `orig` to a size of 0 if it exists. After that, `cat` is called, its stdout connected to `orig`.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t. "The reason why you can't do that: bash processes the redirections first, then executes the command. So by the time grep looks at file_name, it is already empty."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Symlinks are evaluated as you attempt to open a file. Under "normal" circumstances the result of opening a symbolic link is to open the file it references. So:

```
ln -s original_file my_symlink
cat my_symlink > original_file
```

Is very similar to:

```
cat original_file > original_file
```

---

Why does it destroy the content?

In any shell `command > some_file` will first open and truncate (zero) `some_file` and *then* execute `command`, writing the result to `some_file`.

So if you `cat x > x` then the shell will open and truncate `x`, *then* `cat x` will open and read the *truncated* file writing all of it's zero bytes.